# Where and when do I get a chance to review and contest community advisor (CA) assessments of my proposal?

Tags: catalyst

My proposal is now in the "assess QA" phase.
I am expecting to see the assessments, so that I can propose rejection of any that do not meet the guidelines.

Will they appear in Catalyst or be listed elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assessments made by Community advisors are mailed to the proposer as a Google Sheet. The proposer can mark infringements as he finds in the assessment in the sheet. If a proposer has not received he can contact in the related telegram channel. Please refer this [QA Stage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-UuUQ1k6h8)